# How can I serve Blazor Wasm static files?

Tags: web-hosting, blazor-webassembly

When I publish the standalone Blazor Wasm application, I get the following output:

1. "wwwroot" folder, looks like this:
   [wwwroot_folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAHhp.png)
2. web.config file

However, if I just take the content from wwwroot and upload it to my servers website root.
All it gives me is the following error:
Loading...
An unhandled error has occurred. Reload

Is there any tutorial or document that will take me through the correct steps to serve the files from my servers website root.

I have successfully deployed my wasm application to Azure Static Web Apps via github, however, I really really want to serve the files from/as my website.